# SQL union but vertically

Tags: sql, join

recently started with simple queries in SQL

I was wondering if there is a possibility to add data vertically like "union" does horizontally

I have two selection i want to combine

```
month year data1 data2 grouped by month, year
month year data3 data4 grouped by month, year
```

what I'm trying to archive is

```
month year data1 data2 data3 data4
```

Is there any function working like union to archive this? I was trying to do so with "join" but failed horribly

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Can you show us what your query so far? Your question is vague

Comment: You are looking for join operator

Comment: Are you looking to do something like dynamically increase the size of your `SELECT` list? or are you looking to do something like increase the number of `records` returned using a `UNION ALL`?

Comment: imo, [join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) is the way to go. If it's the case, you can group both selections before joining the data.

Comment: A vertical union? That's a join!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like if a `FULL JOIN` is probably what you want. It include all rows from both operands combining rows, that fulfill the expression in the `ON` clause. If there is no matching partner row in the other operand, the columns of the other operand are filled with `NULL`. That's why `coalesce()` is needed to get the year or month.

```
SELECT coalesce (x1.year, x2.year) year,
       coalesce (x1.month, x2.month) month,
       x1.data1,
       x1.data2,
       x2.data3,
       x2.data4
       FROM (<your first grouping query>) x1
            FULL JOIN (<your second grouping query>) x2
                      ON x2.year = x1.year
                         AND x2.month = x1.month;
```

Replace `<your first grouping query>` and `<your second grouping query>` with your first or second query, respectively.

Comment: If you use `full join ... using (year, month)` then then there is no need for the `coalesce()` and the join columns will also only appear once in the output

Comment: This one dear sir is working like a charm. After 2 hours of frustration you really made my day!